# Use Spark to Write Kafka Messages Directly to a File

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

For a class project, I need a Spark Java program to listen as a Kafka consumer and write all of a Kafka topic's received messages to a file (e.g. "/user/zaydh/my_text_file.txt").

I am able to receive the messages in as a `JavaPairReceiverInputDStream` object; I can also convert it to a `JavaDStream<String>` (this is from the Spark Kafka example).

However, I could not find a good Java syntax to write this data to what is a essentially a single log file. I tried using `foreachRDD` on the `JavaDStream` object, but I could not find a clean, parallel-safe way to sink it to a single log file.

I understand this approach is non-traditional or non-ideal, but it is a requirement. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you think of a stream , you got to think of it as something that wont stop giving out data .
Hence if Spark streaming had a way to save all the RDDs coming in to a single file , it would keep growing to a huge size (and the stream isnt supposed to stop remember ? :))
But in this case you can make use of the [saveAsTextFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#saveAsTextFile(java.lang.String))  utility of an RDD,
Which will create many file in your output directory depending on your batch interval  thats specified while creating the streaming context 
`JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1))`

You can then merge these fileparts into one using somthing like [how-to-merge-all-text-files-in-a-directory-into-one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/how-to-merge-all-text-files-in-a-directory-into-one)